# react-bootstrap navbar onToggle capture event

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener, react-bootstrap

Typical react-bootstrap navigation scenario. I've built a custom dropdown (collapse) as I didn't like the bootstrap version. The issue I'm having is in capturing the Navbar onToggle 'event' associated with the screen changing from desktop to mobile 768px. I don't even know if there is such an event as the docs don't say anything about it.

GitHub: https://github.com/haldous2/node_react_login_bootstrap_custom

Demo: [node-two.n2local.com](http://node-two.n2local.com/)

What I ended up doing: Added a 'resize' event listener to detect screen sizes mobile and desktop. When desktop is detected is sets display state for the nav_menu_links div to none and also turns off scroll lock.

What I would like to do: Capture and use the bootstrap navbar toggle event to change display and scroll locks instead of using an event listener.

The following is the mobile half of my render. You can see the menu in question 'nav_menu_links' .. it floats around and hides sometimes.

```
updateDimensions() {
    this.setState({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
    this.isMobile();
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.bodyClick.bind(this));
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.bodyClick.bind(this));
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Mobile>
                <div style={{ paddingTop: '71px' }}></div>
                <Navbar
                    fixedTop
                    collapseOnSelect
                    onToggle={collapsed=>this.navMenuToggle(collapsed)}
                    style={{ maxHeight:'50px', minWidth:'300px' }}
                >
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <a href="/">Node React Login</a>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle />
                    </Navbar.Header>
                </Navbar>
                <div
                    id='nav_menu'
                    style={{
                    position:'fixed',
                    minWidth:'300px',
                    zIndex:'100',
                    top:'52px',
                    right:'0',
                    left:'0'
                }}>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div
                            id='nav_menu_links'
                            ref={(input) => { this.navBarLinks = input; }}
                            style={{
                                display:this.state.nav_menu_links_display,
                                width:'300px',
                                float:'right',
                                backgroundColor:'#FFF',
                                border:'1px solid #CCC'
                            }}
                        >
                            {this.state.navMobile}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        id='nav_menu_search'
                        ref={(input) => { this.navBarSearch = input; }}
                        style={{
                            display:this.state.nav_menu_search_display,
                            width:'300px',
                            float:'right',
                            backgroundColor:'#FFF',
                            border:'1px solid #CCC'
                        }}
                    >
                    Search
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Mobile>
            <Desktop>
                ...
            </Desktop>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out the onToggle event issue; however, I'm forging forward with a mix of custom code along with Bootstrap. I ended up not using the default toggle method of bootstrap and rolling with my own glyphs as buttons. I hope this code can help somebody who might want to do the same. The demo and github have been updated.